# Passing variables through constructors in android

Tags: java, android, client-server

My app transfers images from server to client. The problem now is that only one(the same) image is being sent even though I select a different pic. My server code (where I believe the error is) is as follows:
N.B the classes are in different files.

(String selectedImagePath) is a global variable in my main activity.

```
public void onSendClick(View v) {
            serverSocketThread = new ServerSocketThread(SocketServerPORT, selectedImagePath);
            serverSocketThread.start();
        }
    //*********************pick image**********************///////////////:
        public void onBrowseClick(View v) {

            if (checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(this)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
            }
        }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                    TextView path = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPath);
                    path.setText("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                    imageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                    //btnSend.setClickable(true);
                }
            }
        }

        public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
```

`ServerSocketThread`

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;

    public class ServerSocketThread extends Thread {

        int SocketServerPORT;
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        String selectedImagePath;

        ServerSocketThread(int SocketServerPORT, String selectedImagePath) {
            this.SocketServerPORT = SocketServerPORT;
            this.selectedImagePath = selectedImagePath;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;

            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);

                while (true) {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    FileTxThread fileTxThread = new FileTxThread(socket, this.selectedImagePath);
                    fileTxThread.start();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }

FileTxThread

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.net.Socket;

    public class FileTxThread extends Thread {
        Socket socket;
        Context context;
        String selectedImagePath;

        FileTxThread(Socket socket, String selectedImagePath){
            this.socket = socket;
            this.selectedImagePath = selectedImagePath;
        }

        FileTxThread(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
               /* if(imageView.getDrawable()!=null) {
                    bSend.setClickable(true);
                }*/
                File file = new File(this.selectedImagePath);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];

                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                bis.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


                oos.writeObject(bytes);
                oos.flush();

                socket.close();

                final String sentMsg = "File sent to: " + socket.getInetAddress();

                ((Selector)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, sentMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }});

                Toast.makeText(context, sentMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

It's the same image that seems to be sent, please help me figure out where I am going wrong. I'm not sure if the problem is with my constructors or not.

Comment: I can't see how the question title relates to the question body.

Comment: It's because I suspect that is where the problem is, if u don't mind could u suggest me a better one. thank u

Comment: I can't suggest better, but this one is incorrect as for me. As for the question - have you tried to debug and see what you send and receive on client and server sides?

Comment: It's the same image, the one I chose first.